# how to subscribe the Id of the created object after POST operation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an component where i am adding a new object called `customer` by calling the `api` like this:

```
  public onAdd(): void {
    this.myCustomer = this.customerForm.value; 
    this.myService.addCustomer(this.myCustome).subscribe(
      () => {  // If POST is success
        this.callSuccessMethod(); 
      },
      (error) => { // If POST is failed
       this.callFailureMethod();
      },
    );

 }
```

**Service file:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class MyService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....URL....';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer): Observable<object> {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

  return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
}

}
```

As shown in component code, i have already subscribed the `api` call like this:

```
this.myService.addCustomer(this.myCustome).subscribe(
          () => {  // If POST is success
            .....
          },
          (error) => { // If POST is failed
           ...
          },
        );
```

**But,I want to subscribe the results in another component, I have tried like this:**

```
public  getAddedCustomer() { 
    this.myService.addCustomer().subscribe(
      (data:ICustomer) => { 
        this.addedCustomer.id = data.id; <======
      }
    );
  }
```

I am getting this lint error: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0` since i am not passing any `parameter`.

What is the right approach to subscribe the api call in other components? after **POST** operation.

**Because i want to get added object id for other functionality.**

Comment: How is this "another component" related to the component ? Is there any parent child relationship ?

Comment: There is no parent-child relationship

Comment: I want to get the `added object ID` in the `same component` or in other `component`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it totally depends on the design of your application and the relation between components. You can use Subjects for multicasting the data to multiple subscribers.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class MyService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....URL....';
 private latestAddedCustomer = new Subject();
 public latestAddedCustomer$ = this.latestAddedCustomer.asObservable()
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer): Observable<object> {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

  return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer).pipe(map((data) => this.latestAddedCustomer.next(data)));
}

}
```

and subscribing to the subject as follows

```
this.latestAddedCustomer$.subscribe()
```

should get you the latest added customer details. Even though i would not do this the way its written. I would basically write a seperate service to share the data between the components or would write a cache service if its used across the application. But the idea here is to use the concept of Subjects. You can read more about it [Here](https://www.akveo.com/blog/understanding-observables-and-subjects-in-rxjs-multicasting-values/)

Comment: Actually i have also written separate `services` for communication between components, but in this `scenario` i should get `response` from the api only.

Comment: What do you mean by api only ?. You mean the observable should be shared between the components ?

Comment: Means from `addCustomer` method present in `services(myService)` file, Here i am calling the api.

Comment: Yeah thats what the answer says. After the response comes, emit the value using the subject. So whoever has subscribed to it would get the value.